# Memory allocations of string in Dart

Tags: dart, memory-management

I have a summary of how a **new** keyword in Java creates a **String("string")**, 2 objects or just variable = "string" while creating 1 object. What is the memory allocation for String in Dart?

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's complicated.

The Java `String` constructor is a copy-constructor. It creates a new object (new identity) with the same content.
The corresponding Dart operation would be `String.fromCharCodes(otherString.codeUnits)`.

A Dart string literal, like `"string"` is a compile-time constant. It'll likely not require any memory allocation at runtime. It exists in the initial program before it starts running.

Doing `string1 + string2` or `"foo $v1 or $v2"` will allocate new strings with the length of all the strings being concatenated.